# TI Beacons not working with CoreLocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ibeacon, clbeacon

I am trying to connect TI beacons to device but I am unable to connect. The downloaded the various sample codes to connect the beacons but seems like everyone has used the estimator beacons .
is there any difference in estimator and TI beacons .
What UUID should i give in source code.
I am giving from the mac  terminal one by running uuidgen

Comment: Your question could use some more specifics. Do you mean that your TI beacons are not being detected by Core Location? Do you use ranging or monitoring? Can you edit your question and add some code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

In order to detect your TI with CoreLocation, you need to make sure it is transmitting an iBeacon-compatible format, and if so, know the ProximityUUID to configure in CoreLocation.  I suspect that the beacon may not be iBeacon compatible at all.

If you can post more information on the beacon model, then perhaps folks can help more.